# select with single case blocks, adding default: unblocks

Tags: go

While testing some code with something like this:

```golang
// ch := make(chan error)

for {
    select {
      case <- ch:
           println("here")
    }
}
```

I notice that if I don't add a `default` the code blocks:

```golang
for {
    select {
       case <- ch:
            println("here")
       default:
    }
}
```

In case that the block is required, could't be better then just use `range`, something like:

```golang
for {
    for _ = range <- ch {
        println("here")
    }
}
```

Or is there any difference/advantage of using `select` over `range` for this case ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1- When you are dealing with one channel, it is OK to use `for`,
consider this working code ( [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wf96VH3uDG) ):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    close(ch)
    for range ch {
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

This will empty the channel.
Note: you should `close` the channel or you should use `break` statement to finish that loop.

---

2- When you are dealing with more channels you may use `select`, like this ( [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BEpi-ZyWQF) ):

```golang
for {
    select {
    case <-pause:
        fmt.Println("pause")
        select {
        case <-play:
            fmt.Println("play")
        case <-quit:
            wg.Done()
            return
        }
    case <-quit:
        wg.Done()
        return
    default:
        work()
    }
}
```

---

3- Using nil  and closed channel ( [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PStmX-aXVm) ):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var quit chan struct{} // nil

    select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("1")
    default:
        fmt.Println("2") // This runs
    }

    quit = make(chan struct{}, 1)

    select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("10")
    default:
        fmt.Println("20") // This runs
    }

    quit <- struct{}{} // send

    select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("100") // This runs
    default:
        fmt.Println("200")
    }

    close(quit)

    select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("1000") // This runs
    default:
        fmt.Println("2000")
    }

    select {
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("10000") // This runs
    default:
        fmt.Println("20000")
    }
}
```

output:

```
2
20
100
1000
10000
```

---

[Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

> A "select" statement chooses which of a set of possible send or
> receive operations will proceed. It looks similar to a "switch"
> statement but with the cases all referring to communication
> operations.
>
> A case with a RecvStmt may assign the result of a RecvExpr to one or
> two variables, which may be declared using a short variable
> declaration. The RecvExpr must be a (possibly parenthesized) receive
> operation. There can be at most one default case and it may appear
> anywhere in the list of cases.

Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive
> operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
> statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
> the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive
> from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side
> effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any)
> communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the
> left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or
> assignment are not yet evaluated. If one or more of the communications
> can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform
> pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that
> case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement
> blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed. Unless
> the selected case is the default case, the respective communication
> operation is executed. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short
> variable declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions
> are evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned. The
> statement list of the selected case is executed. Since communication
> on nil channels can never proceed, a select with only nil channels and
> no default case blocks forever.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, it seems that a simple loop would suffice:

```
for _ = range ch {
    fmt.Println("drain")
}
```

Select is required, if you have *multiple* goroutines to handle. The tour has an example of [range and close](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4).

Another case for `select` would be idempotent channel closes: https://play.golang.org/p/_Ol42BvuuS.

Comment: One use for single-case selects is idempotent channel closes: https://play.golang.org/p/_Ol42BvuuS

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one case in select then it's better to `use for range instead of for { select {} } (gosimple)` which is a `S1000` golint check.

`for range` code is like:

```
for range ch {
    fmt.Println("here")
}
```

Comment: What if I want to check that the channel is closed? e.g., is it possible to do `value, ok := <-ch` inside a for-range statement?

Comment: Actually I found this to be really helpful, appears that the close will break the loop: https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels